# How create 4 custom footer links blocks with titles Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

[image: Custom footer Magento 2]
How create 4 custom footer links block Magento 2?
There are many similar themes, but unfortunately there is no solution for several blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create 4 different **static block** for **footer**. And define them in to default.xml file inside your `Vendor_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container" htmlClass="page-footer">
        <container name="footer-wrap" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
            <container name="footer-row-1" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row is-flex footer-links">
                <container name="footer_col_1" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 footer-col col-md-2 border-left">
                    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_col_1_inner">
                      <arguments>
                         <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-col-1</argument>
                      </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <container name="footer_col_2" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 footer-col col-md-2 border-left">
                    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_col_2_inner">
                      <arguments>
                         <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-col-2</argument>
                      </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <container name="footer_col_3" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 footer-col col-md-2 border-left">
                    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_col_3_inner">
                      <arguments>
                         <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-col-3</argument>
                      </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <container name="footer_col_4" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 footer-col col-md-2 border-left">
                    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_col_4_inner">
                      <arguments>
                         <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-col-4</argument>
                      </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <container name="footer_col_5" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-xs-12 margintop-30sm footer-col col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                </container>
            </container>
        </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

add your block id in above code. and inside your each block you can mention your custom links. Hope this helps.